# Convergence of infinite product of complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, infinite-product

In my studies of complex analysis, I have encountered this question:

> We are asked to find the complex numbers $ z $ for which the infinite countable product converges $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-z^n)$$ to a nonzero number.

I know what it means for a product to converge (its sequence of partial products converges to nonzero number) but I cannot find any numbers for which this converges, perhaps the ratio test? Though when I try to apply it it doesn't seem to work. I thought to split to cases when $|z|>1,|z|<1,|z|=1$ but again intractable. I need to find all complex numbers for which the product converges and to show that is indeed everything. Thanks to all helpers.
******EDIT: fixed it to converge to nonzero so complex analysts won't disagree with me on terminology.

Comment: If $z=e^{2\pi i \alpha}$ with $\alpha$ rational, will converge to zero.

Comment: If $|z|>1,$ diverges.

Comment: For $\alpha=p/q$ rational, with $p$ and $q$ integer, $n \alpha$ is an integer so $z^n=1.$  Also, $1-z^n = (1-z)(1+z+z^2+ \cdots + z^{n-1})$, so as $n\to\infty$, the series (a term of the product) diverges.

Comment: Note that for infinite products, the terminology is usually that the product **diverges** to $0$.

Comment: Okay.  Not disagreeing.  Why is that? (diverges to 0)

Comment: @mjw: See the comments on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3676506/427810). TL;DR seems to be that stating it this way seems to be compatible with most theorems (analogues of those for summations) without having to treat edge cases.

Comment: kroner: I can't add anything more concrete than what @mjw did. However, I'll refer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569152/dense-set-in-the-unit-circle-reference-needed) which says that $\{z^n : n \in \Bbb N\}$ is dense in the unit circle $S^1$ when $z = e^{i\pi\alpha}$ with $\alpha$ irrational. However, concluding anything from this seems difficult since we see that $1 - z^n$ can get arbitrarily close to both $0$ and $2$. Since $1 - z^n \not\to 1$, what we can conclude is that the product cannot converge. (But it could *diverge* to $0$(!))

Comment: @kroner: I won't comment on case $|z| \neq 1$ since I didn't really understand the currently given answer. You are correct for the rational argument (though you probably mean rational argument of $\pi$). However, for the irrational, I just said that it *could* diverge to $0$. I did not prove that. (I don't even know whether to believe that.) All I concluded was that it cannot *converge*. So, it may either diverge to $0$, to $\infty$, or genuinely not have any limit (some oscillatory behaviour).

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I think you overestimate the usage of the terminology "diverges to $0.$" It seems to me to be a weird old school thing. Rudin, for example, doesn't mention it in RCA.

Comment: @zhw: possibly. I wouldn't defend my stance much. However, it does have the nice benefit here that $a_n \not\to 1$ lets us conclude that $\prod a_n$ doesn't converge. (Analogous to the summation case with $0$.) If we counted $0$ as convergence, it would have to be addressed separately. (But yes, I agree that it's not difficult to add that; just personal preference.)

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It converges as an infinite product if $|z|<1$. It is zero when $z$ is a root of unity,
but complex analysts would claim it diverges then too. It is certainly divergent for all
other $z$. For $|z|<1$ the (principal) logarithms of $1-z^n$ are asymptotic to $-z^n$
so the product converges.

For $|z|>1$ the terms do not converge to $1$, while for $|z|=1$ things are much
more delicate.

Answer (score 2):

Just to discuss $|z|<1$:

$$\displaystyle Q = \prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-z^n)$$

$$\log Q = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \log (1-z^n)$$

The $n$th term of the series is $a_n=\log(1-z^n)$ and $\lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n} =|z|$, so if $|z|<1$, the series (and thus the product) converges.

Comment: Well, yes.  To converge or diverge (see _heated_ discussion above for vocabulary!) to zero, one of the terms needs to go to zero, or $z^n\to 1$, which is impossible for $|z|<1.$

Comment: Looking again at the other answer, it already has been stated that $\log (1-z^n) \sim -z^n$, so that really covered it already.

Comment: @mjw: I am not sure if I agree with "one of the terms needs to go to zero". Consider the product $\prod a_n$ where each $a_n$ is $1/2$. The infinite product diverges to $0$ but the terms are all constant.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Thank you.  Let's rephrase that.  Here $\forall n, |b_n| >0$ and $b_n\to 1$, where $b_n$ is a term in the product.  (Writing $b_n$ where $a_n=\log b_n$ and $a_n$ is defined above to be a term in the sum.)